# How can i get the live value outside of window.resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get the value of the current height after the window.resize?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    currHeight = $('#window-fixed').height();        
});

console.log( currHeight );
//Uncaught ReferenceError: currHeight is not defined

$('a.stp').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).data('id');        

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ( $(href).offset().top ) - currHeight
    }, 1200);        

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Surely you can get it but important question here is **How & where you want to use it**

Comment: Oh, sorry for it. I will update the question. Thanks :)

Comment: "Roko C. Buljan" answered it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $winFix    = $('#window-fixed'),  // Cache your elements!
    currHeight = $winFix.height();    // Say hello to your variable!

$(window).resize(function(){
    currHeight = $winFix.height(); // modify your variable      
});

console.log( currHeight ); // nnn

$('a.stp').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).data('id');        

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ( $(href).offset().top ) - currHeight // Reuse it
    }, 1200);        

});
```

You were running into a **ReferenceError** cause the scope of your variable was not defined in a parent function, therefore was not reachable to all your inner functions.

Comment: Thank you Roko! :) Well Done!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `currHeight` as global variable like:

```
var currHeight = 0;

$(window).resize(function(){
    currHeight = $('#window-fixed').height();        
}).resize();    //  Calling resize() method on page load only

console.log( currHeight );  // You will get the `window-fixed` height here now
```